# How to troubleshoot a gas fireplace that shuts down randomly?

Tags: fireplace, pilot-light

I am having some weird issues with my propane gas fireplace insert.
I've noticed that the pilot light will go out a few times a day but will restart after a few minutes.

Also sometimes the fireplace will shut down before it reaches the temperature set at the thermostat. And sometimes when it shuts down before reaching temp it is a hard shut down. The Fire goes out the pilot goes out and the fan shuts off all at once (Normally the fan runs for some time after the flame goes out as a cool down mode).  When this happens I have to turn the fireplace off and then on again for it to start working again.

And lastly sometimes when the fireplace is not running the pilot light will go out and will not relight and then after about 15 minutes the fan turns on.  The fan will continue to run until I shut the unit down and turn it back on.

How do I go about troubleshooting my Xtrordinair 564 HO fireplace,circa 2014.

Comment: I would call the HVAC service rather than troubleshoot online.

Comment: Do you happen to be having some unusually cold weather outside where your propane tank is stored?  Propane tanks contain liquid propane with propane gas above that. If it's too cold outside, it's possible that the liquid in the tank can't turn to gas fast enough to satisfy the need your fireplace is demanding.

Comment: The weather has not been colder than normal, actually it's been a pretty mild winter.  And no other gas appliance in the house is having problems (Basement heater and boiler for back bedrooms).  And All Appliances have been installed and working properly for years.